# Reading a Nullable Datetime field with LINQ giving odd results

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime, nullable

I am reading a datetime field from an SQL database, defined as datetime, null.

This is my read:

```
var _dataContextOrders = new OrderClassesDataContext();
var ordersData = (from o in _dataContextOrders.Orders
                 join s in _dataContextOrders.FMSSuppliers on o.SupplierID equals s.ID
                 join os in _dataContextOrders.StatusCodes on o.OrderStatusCode equals os.StatusCode1
                 join pc in _dataContextOrders.Persons on o.CreatorPersonID equals pc.ID
                 select new OrderData 
                 {
                    ID=o.ID,                                  
                    ApprovedDate= o.ApprovedDate                                  
                 }).SingleOrDefault(o => o.ID == _intOrderId);
return ordersData;
```

The field ApprovedDate is coming back as null even where it has a value.
The OrderData record is defined here:

```
public class OrderData
{
   public int ID { get; set; }        
   public DateTime? ApprovedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I know the field has a value, as I have checked in SQL. How do I get it to return a value?

Comment: It would be great to see small piece of code which reproduces your problem

Comment: Indeed. Both pieces of code could be made *much* shorter if you just had a single property (possibly plus an ID). It would then make it simpler for you to format the code more sensibly, too...

Comment: Have you tried `ApprovedDate = o.ApprovedDate.Value` ?

Comment: ApprovedDate = o.ApprovedDate.Value did not work.

Comment: My mistake - it worked. The previous error had caused it to overwrite the data.